# How to export statistics_log data cumulatively to the desired Excel sheet in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have selected to export tables at the end of model execution to an Excel file, and I would like that data to accumulate on the same Excel sheet after every stop and start of the model. As of now, every stop and start just exports that 1 run's data and overwrites what was there previously. I may be approaching the method of exporting multiple runs wrong/inefficiently but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Best method is to export the raw data, as you do (if it is not too large).

However, 2 improvements:

1. manage your output data yourself, i.e. do not rely on the standard export tables but only write data that you really need. Check this [help article](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#insert) to learn how to write your own data
2. in your custom output data tables, add additional identification columns such as `date_of_run`. I often use `iteration` and `replication` columns to also identify from which of those the data stems.

### custom csv approach

Alternative approach is to write create your own csv file programmatically, this is possible with Java code. Then, you can create a new one (with a custom filename) after any run:

First, define a “Text file” element as below:
[image]

Then, use this code below to create your own csv with a custom name and write to it:

```
File outputDirectory = new File("outputs");
outputDirectory.mkdir();
String outputFileNameWithExtension = outputDirectory.getPath()+File.separator+"output_file.csv";

file.setFile(outputFileNameWithExtension, Mode.WRITE_APPEND);

// create header
file.println(        "col_1"+","+"col_2");

// Write data from dbase table                                
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(my_dbase_table).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
        file.println(        row.get( my_dbase_table.col_1) + "," + 
                                        row.get( my_dbase_table.col_2));
}
file.close();
```

Comment: And this code would have to be put in the Java actions of the Simulation properties I am assuming? If done correctly, this process should export the data of each run to the same csv file, correct?

Comment: yes to the first. To the second: if you change the file name each time you call it, it creates a new file. else overwrites the previous one. Use that to your advantage

Comment: The original problem is that I want the data to accumulate on a single file, not to overwrite.

Comment: then you have to code that first

Comment: That was/is the basis of my question. I have edited the question to make that clear.